# getView don't return data

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter

I want to display image + tel number.I have create a class for Contact :

```
public class Contact {

    private int CTC_ID;
    private byte[]  CTC_IMAGE;
    public String CTC_NOM;
    public String CTC_NUMERO;

    public Contact(){
    }

    public Contact(byte[] CTC_IMAGE, String CTC_NOM, String CTC_NUMERO){
        this.CTC_IMAGE = CTC_IMAGE;
        this.CTC_NOM = CTC_NOM;
        this.CTC_NUMERO = CTC_NUMERO;
    }
    public Contact(String CTC_NOM, String CTC_NUMERO){
        this.CTC_NOM = CTC_NOM;
        this.CTC_NUMERO = CTC_NUMERO;
    }



    public int getCTC_ID(){
        return CTC_ID;
    }
    public byte[] getCTC_IMAGE(){return CTC_IMAGE; }
    public String getCTC_NOM() {
        return CTC_NOM;
    }
    public String getCTC_NUMERO() {
        return CTC_NUMERO;
    }

    public void setCTC_ID(int CTC_ID) {
        this.CTC_ID = CTC_ID;
    }
    public void setCTC_IMAGE(byte[] CTC_IMAGE) { this.CTC_IMAGE = CTC_IMAGE;}
    public void setCTC_NOM(String CTC_NOM) { this.CTC_NOM = CTC_NOM;}
    public void setCTC_NUMERO(String CTC_NUMERO) {
        this.CTC_NUMERO = CTC_NUMERO;
    }


    public String toString(){
        return "ID : "+CTC_ID+"\nimage : "+CTC_IMAGE+"\nnom : "+CTC_NOM+"\nnumero : "+CTC_NUMERO;
    }
}
```

For add contact into list I have my databaseHelper in methode fetchAllContactDetail :

```
public ArrayList<Contact> fetchAllContactDetail() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ArrayList<Contact> contactListe = new ArrayList<>();

    Cursor mCursor = db.query(TABLE_CONTACT, new String[]{"CTC_ID _id", KEY_CTC_IMAGE, KEY_CTC_IMAGE, KEY_CTC_NOM, KEY_CTC_NUMERO}, null, null, null, null, null);

    if (mCursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            byte[] image = mCursor.getBlob(mCursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_CTC_IMAGE));
            String name = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_CTC_NOM));
            String numero = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_CTC_NUMERO));
            contactListe.add(new Contact(image, name, numero));
        } while (mCursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return contactListe;
}
```

I have create ContactAdapter extends BaseAdapter :

```
public class ContactAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList<Contact>();


    // Constructor
    public ContactAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Contact> contactList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.contactList.addAll(contactList);
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return contactList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return contactList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    private class ViewHolder{
        ImageView img;
        TextView name;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        View row = view;
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();

        if(row == null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_item, null);
        }

        Contact contact = contactList.get(position);

        if (contactList != null) {
            holder.name = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.name);
            holder.img = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.img);

            holder.name.setText(contact.getCTC_NUMERO());
            byte[] contactImage = contact.getCTC_IMAGE();
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(contactImage, 0, contactImage.length);
            holder.img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            row.setTag(holder);
        }
        return row;

    }
}
```

And I return this in my mainActivity :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ListView lstViewContact;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

                lstViewContact = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvContact);

                displayContact();

}

    public void displayContact() {

        //On ouvre la base de données pour écrire dedans
        DatabaseHelper dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        final ContactAdapter contactAdapter = new ContactAdapter(this, dbHelper.fetchAllContactDetail());
        lstViewContact.setAdapter(contactAdapter);
    }
}
```

My database have 2 contact and it's return by contactListe

[image]

In my ContactAdapter the

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return contactList.size();
}
```

Return 2 it's ok.

I don't say where is the problem.

Thank's all for you're help.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();

if(row == null) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_item, null);
}
```

with

```
ViewHolder holder;

if(row == null) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_item, viewGroup, false);

    holder = new ViewHolder();
    // TODO: Initialise holder values, like
    // holder.name = row.findViewById(R.id.name);
    row.setTag(holder);
} else {
    holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
}
```

Comment: I try this but don't changed my problem x)

Comment: Again the same problem :'(

Comment: Is it crashing or data is empty ?

Comment: is empty no data in my mainactivity :(

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in your getView() implementation

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    View row = view;
    ViewHolder holder = null;

    if(row == null){
        holder=new ViewHolder();
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_item, null);
        holder.name = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.name);
        holder.img = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.img);
        row.setTag(holder);
    }else{
    holder=row.getTag();}

    Contact contact = contactList.get(position);

    if (contactList != null) {

        holder.name.setText(contact.getCTC_NUMERO());
        byte[] contactImage = contact.getCTC_IMAGE();
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(contactImage, 0, contactImage.length);
        holder.img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    }
    return row;

}
```

This is about the holder intitialization problem.

paste the above code and try.

Comment: Again the same problem :'(

Comment: And the problem iss?

Comment: 1. Can you copy the result to an ArrayList and try. 2. if its not working check with dummy data. 3. If it working the problem is not in adapter. And change the paramter passing from connstructor to setter method and call notifydataset changed.